# Get time period ( hour / half-hour / quarter hour ) of day

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, datetime

Is there any way to download every hour and another period of the day?
I mean exactly the result in the form of a list.

```
[
"00:00", // start of the day e.q 14.03
"01:00",
"02:00",
....
"23:00",
"00:00  // end of the day e.q 14.03
]
```

and

```
[
"00:00", // start of the day e.q 14.03
"00:30",
"01:00"
"01:30"
....
"00:00  // end of the day e.q 14.03
]
```

and

```
[
"00:00", // start of the day e.q 14.03
"00:15",
"00:30"
"00:45"
"01:00"
....
"00:00  // end of the day e.q 14.03
]
```

14.03 means March 14 for the sake of the example.

Of course it is possible to add this manually, but it would not be a particularly elegant solution.  Is it possible to do it without explicitly declaring constants as values of each hour ?
The best solution would be a function without using loops and if else constructions.

I have not yet been able to find an implementation of such a solution. I myself also spend another hour on this without success. I need it to implement a functionality that creates a Map or a list of pairs from a list of such e.q hours:

```
[
"00:00 - 01:00",
"01:00 - 02:00",
"02:00 - 03:00 "
//.......
"23:00 - 00:00"
]
```

Has anyone had occasion to implement such a problem and would be able to help?

Comment: Use the `LocalTime` class and a loop.

Comment: What does "e.q. 14.03" mean in all of your comments? (And why is it the same at the start of one day and at the start of the next?)

Comment: 14.03 means March 14. Here's an example. Questions in brackets I don't really understand what you are asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function to generate a `Sequence<LocalTime>` like this:

```
fun generateTimesOfDay(interval: java.time.Duration) = sequence {
    if (interval > java.time.Duration.ofDays(1)) {
        repeat(2) { yield(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT) }
        return@sequence
    }
    var time = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT
    while (true) {
        yield(time)
        val newTime = time + interval
        if (newTime > time) {
            time = newTime
        } else {
            break // passed or reached midnight
        }
    }
    yield(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT) // Midnight the next day to end last period
}
```

Then you have all the LocalTimes you can use with `toString()` or with `.format()` and some DateTimeFormatter to format them how you like. You can use `zipWithNext()` to create the time ranges.

```
val x = generateTimesOfDay(java.time.Duration.ofMinutes(15))
println(x.toList())
println(
    x.zipWithNext { a, b -> "$a - $b" }.toList()
)
```

Note, I'm using fully qualified `java.time.Duration` to avoid conflicts with the Kotlin standard library Duration class.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks a lot it solves my problem.

Comment: Btw, Is there any other way to get this without the loop ?

Comment: I don't know how you can create anything repetitive in programming without a loop. The options are always to either use a loop or hard code every step that would have been in the loop, which would be silly.

Comment: Of course you are right ;) Thanks for your reply